# How to Press the button with javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

How to Press the button with JavaScript.

```
function fnLoginPressEnter(obj) {
  if (this.event.keyCode == 13) {
    Ncucu.Login(document.forms[0]);
  }
}
```

that's so wrong

```
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("fnLoginPressEnter");
```

Answer (score 1):

use onkeydown="if(event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('[YOUR_BUTTON_ID]').click()"

Comment: Can write in full as it will be? PLZ!

Comment: html code

Textfield1:

<input type = "text" id = "textfield" onkeydown="if(event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('btnSubmit').click()>

<input type = "button" value = "Submit" id="btnsubmit">

Answer (score 0):

If you using jQuery, you can do this:

```
$('#button_id').click();
```

or you can create manually an click event:

```
var el=document.getElementById('button_id');                            
if (!el.dispatchEvent) {
                            el.fireEvent('onclick');
                        } else {
                            var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
                            e.initMouseEvent('click', false, true, top, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0,
                                    null);
                            el.dispatchEvent(e);
                        }
```

Comment: OP doesn't mention jQuery, just JavaScript.

Comment: How does it cause through webBrowser1.Document

Answer (score 0):

Use this one with your requirement like onkeyup

eg:

```
onkeyup="javascript:KeyUp(event);"

function KeyUp(event)
var v = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.charCode;
  if (v == "13") {
    document.getElementById('btnSubmit').click();
  }
```